# Get FLOPS using GPflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpflow

Is it somehow possible in `GPflow` to get FLOPS? I have found an example using `Tensorflow` but have no idea how to use this in a `GPflow` context:

```py
g = tf.Graph()
run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
with g.as_default():
    A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [25,16] ))
    B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [16,9] ))
    C = tf.matmul(A,B)

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(g, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
    if flops is not None:
        print('TF stats gives',flops.total_float_ops)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dig a little bit in the source code of GPFlow. The key to make it work is to intercept the Tensorflow op that you want to profile before GPFlow's AutoFlows creates a new graph.

In my case, I wanted to profile the `predict()` function. The function you need is `model._build_predict()` (there's one equivalent for log-likelihood).
Here's how it works:

```py
gpflow.reset_default_graph_and_session()
kernel = gpflow.kernels.RBF(1)
model = gpflow.models.GPR(X, Y, kernel)

run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
with model.enquire_session(session=None) as tf_session:
    predict_op = model._build_predict(X)

    tf_session.run(predict_op, options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE), 
                      run_metadata=run_metadata)

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
    prof = tf.profiler.profile(tf_session.graph, run_meta=run_metadata, 
                                cmd='op', options=opts)

print('FOps: ', prof.total_float_ops)
```